# How to migrate the vertx timer in cluster mode？

Tags: timer, cluster-computing, vert.x

i deploy multiple vertx instance in different server with cluster mode use HazelcastCluster. if there is a  vertx.timer  in one instance , when this instance unexpected shutdown, how can i migrate this timer to other instance and make sure this timer can run correctly in the right delay

bad english I apologize，but i really need help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Vert.x timers are not clustered. What you could do is:

- starting your cluster nodes in [High-Availability](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_high_availability_and_fail_over) mode
- deploy the verticle to a HA node.

> When Vert.x runs with HA enabled, if a Vert.x instance where a
> verticle runs fails or dies, the verticle is redeployed automatically
> on another vert.x instance of the cluster.